# import {legend} from "@d3/color-legend" What is this in a html code? is there a <script src="***"> available?

Tags: d3.js, legend

I am following this code block:
https://observablehq.com/@d3/stacked-bar-chart
I want to make a same legend,
but I am not writing d3 in a js file,
I am using html with script,
I am wondering is there a link available to embed it in html? many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you can, ObservableHQ has it's own ecosystem for packages like this.

If you click on the name `d3/color-legend`, you go [to this page](https://observablehq.com/@d3/color-legend). You can copy the code contents, but you can't seem to be able to download it, especially not in a format that can be imported with `<script src="">`. You can try instead to copy it into your code base with very few changes:

```js
function legend({
  color,
  title,
  tickSize = 6,
  width = 320,
  height = 44 + tickSize,
  marginTop = 18,
  marginRight = 0,
  marginBottom = 16 + tickSize,
  marginLeft = 0,
  ticks = width / 64,
  tickFormat,
  tickValues
} = {}) {
  const svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .style("overflow", "visible")
    .style("display", "block");

  let tickAdjust = g => g.selectAll(".tick line").attr("y1", marginTop + marginBottom - height);
  let x;

  // Continuous
  if (color.interpolate) {
    const n = Math.min(color.domain().length, color.range().length);

    x = color.copy().rangeRound(d3.quantize(d3.interpolate(marginLeft, width - marginRight), n));

    svg.append("image")
      .attr("x", marginLeft)
      .attr("y", marginTop)
      .attr("width", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
      .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
      .attr("xlink:href", ramp(color.copy().domain(d3.quantize(d3.interpolate(0, 1), n))).toDataURL());
  }

  // Sequential
  else if (color.interpolator) {
    x = Object.assign(color.copy()
      .interpolator(d3.interpolateRound(marginLeft, width - marginRight)), {
        range() {
          return [marginLeft, width - marginRight];
        }
      });

    svg.append("image")
      .attr("x", marginLeft)
      .attr("y", marginTop)
      .attr("width", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
      .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
      .attr("xlink:href", ramp(color.interpolator()).toDataURL());

    // scaleSequentialQuantile doesn’t implement ticks or tickFormat.
    if (!x.ticks) {
      if (tickValues === undefined) {
        const n = Math.round(ticks + 1);
        tickValues = d3.range(n).map(i => d3.quantile(color.domain(), i / (n - 1)));
      }
      if (typeof tickFormat !== "function") {
        tickFormat = d3.format(tickFormat === undefined ? ",f" : tickFormat);
      }
    }
  }

  // Threshold
  else if (color.invertExtent) {
    const thresholds = color.thresholds ? color.thresholds() // scaleQuantize
      :
      color.quantiles ? color.quantiles() // scaleQuantile
      :
      color.domain(); // scaleThreshold

    const thresholdFormat = tickFormat === undefined ? d => d :
      typeof tickFormat === "string" ? d3.format(tickFormat) :
      tickFormat;

    x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-1, color.range().length - 1])
      .rangeRound([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(color.range())
      .join("rect")
      .attr("x", (d, i) => x(i - 1))
      .attr("y", marginTop)
      .attr("width", (d, i) => x(i) - x(i - 1))
      .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
      .attr("fill", d => d);

    tickValues = d3.range(thresholds.length);
    tickFormat = i => thresholdFormat(thresholds[i], i);
  }

  // Ordinal
  else {
    x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(color.domain())
      .rangeRound([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(color.domain())
      .join("rect")
      .attr("x", x)
      .attr("y", marginTop)
      .attr("width", Math.max(0, x.bandwidth() - 1))
      .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
      .attr("fill", color);

    tickAdjust = () => {};
  }

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
      .ticks(ticks, typeof tickFormat === "string" ? tickFormat : undefined)
      .tickFormat(typeof tickFormat === "function" ? tickFormat : undefined)
      .tickSize(tickSize)
      .tickValues(tickValues))
    .call(tickAdjust)
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.append("text")
      .attr("x", marginLeft)
      .attr("y", marginTop + marginBottom - height - 6)
      .attr("fill", "currentColor")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .text(title));

  return svg.node();
}

function ramp(color, n = 256) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = n;
  canvas.height = 1;
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    context.fillStyle = color(i / (n - 1));
    context.fillRect(i, 0, 1, 1);
  }
  return canvas;
}

legend({
  color: d3.scaleSequential([0, 100], d3.interpolateViridis),
  title: "Temperature (°F)"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Haven't tried it, but [this approach](https://gist.github.com/tophtucker/87f02769353208d625c4762a02a3ad55) may be of some use.